# Must I use the package name specifed in my Android manifest throughout my app?

Tags: android, package, google-play

I developed an application, under a namespace my friend and I used for joint ventures.

I've since migrated that app to my personal developer account, and must continue to use the same package name in the manifest file, else it will appear as a new app in the market, etc.

It seems odd to continue using that package name throughout the app (it was released in early 2010 when we first started learning, and the update I'm planning will be a complete rewrite), and I'd rather use my package prefix.

Can I leave the old package name in the AndroidManifest.xml file, but use the new package prefix throughout the app, and explicitly qualify any `Activity`s, `Service`s or `Receiver`s etc, in my manifest or will that cause some issue when I update the app?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
--> package="com.ouroldjointsite.theapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application>
        <activity
-->         android:name="uk.co.ataulmunim.theapp.TheAppActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That is, the `package` attribute the only place the Play Store will check to see if an application is the same? I understand I'll still have to sign it with the same key as before.

On a side note, is it discouraged to do this, even if it works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the Activity's package name, just not the Application's package name.

And yes, an Activity's package name can be different than an application's package name. It's just that when you use the `Android New Project...` wizard to start a new project, it just assumes that the Application's package name will be the same as the Activity's package name.

Comment: @ataulm: I saw that this post is in 2012. Just wondering after you change the Activity's package name, will it affect your update? This is because I am planning to change mine as well without changing the Application's package name but I am not sure if will affect uploading to Google Play as well as the existing user whom had downloaded the application.

Comment: @LeeYiHong, Just try it. I don't think it will make a difference. The worst that could happen is that Google Play doesn't accept the update, but again I don't think that's going to happen and right now, I'm just too lazy to track down a definitive answer from the official documentation.

Comment: Thank you :) I will give it a try and let you know if there is/are any problem that I will face due to the the above change :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to.

One note is that some services, such as Google Cloud Messaging require being put in your application package directory, as named after the android application package.

But aside from those two files, in my projects I have everything in a `bundle` package